# Android flavor source sets does not support xml svg drawable

Tags: android

My project have same resource xml svg drawable ic_icon_user_head.xml in main resource drawable directory and xinyuetang resource drawable directory. At last gradle select main ic_icon_user_head.xml instead of xinyueyang for xinyuetang flavor. png resource does not have this kind of issue. Would you like to let me know how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

flavorDimensions "product"
productFlavors {
    xinhunan {
        applicationId "com.dingtai.wxhn.activity"
    }

    xinyuetang {
        applicationId "cn.com.voc.xhncloud.ceshi"
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_user_head"
```